# Gradient of a Loss Function for an SVM

Tags: python, computer-vision, svm, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I'm working on [this](http://cs231n.github.io/) class on convolutional neural networks.  I've been trying to implement the gradient of a loss function for an svm and (I have a copy of the solution) I'm having trouble understanding why the solution is correct.

On [this](http://cs231n.github.io/optimization-1/#gradcompute) page it defines the gradient of the loss function to be as follows:
[image: Class course notes of cs231n]
In my code I my analytic gradient matches with the numeric one when implemented in code as follows:

```
 dW = np.zeros(W.shape) # initialize the gradient as zero

  # compute the loss and the gradient
  num_classes = W.shape[1]
  num_train = X.shape[0]
  loss = 0.0
  for i in xrange(num_train):
    scores = X[i].dot(W)
    correct_class_score = scores[y[i]]
    for j in xrange(num_classes):
      if j == y[i]:
        if margin > 0:
            continue
      margin = scores[j] - correct_class_score + 1 # note delta = 1
      if margin > 0:
        dW[:, y[i]] += -X[i]
        dW[:, j] += X[i] # gradient update for incorrect rows
        loss += margin
```

However, it seems like, from the notes, that `dW[:, y[i]]` should be changed every time `j == y[i]` since we subtract the the loss whenever `j == y[i]`.  I'm very confused why the code is not:

```
  dW = np.zeros(W.shape) # initialize the gradient as zero

  # compute the loss and the gradient
  num_classes = W.shape[1]
  num_train = X.shape[0]
  loss = 0.0
  for i in xrange(num_train):
    scores = X[i].dot(W)
    correct_class_score = scores[y[i]]
    for j in xrange(num_classes):
      if j == y[i]:
        if margin > 0:
            dW[:, y[i]] += -X[i]
            continue
      margin = scores[j] - correct_class_score + 1 # note delta = 1
      if margin > 0:
        dW[:, j] += X[i] # gradient update for incorrect rows
        loss += margin
```

and the loss would change when `j == y[i]`.  Why are they both being computed when `J != y[i]`?

Comment: " from the notes, that dW[:, y[i]] should be changed every time j == y[i] since we subtract the the loss whenever j == y[i]. " Isn't the summation symbol summing over j NOT equal to y[i]?

Comment: Looking at it now, that does seem to be the case.  What's throwing me off is when it's written "For the other rows where j !=yi the gradient is...".  It sounds like the first one is in the case where j==yi.  What is the correct implication here?   Also (maybe related), why is there a sum in the first function but not in the second?

Comment: There are gradients with respect to different variables here. The first one is with respect to j == y_i (note that on the left, it's grad_{y_i}), whose expression involves a sum of all the j's not equal to y_i; the second one is with respect to each j not equal to y_i.

Comment: Ahh, now I see.  Why is there only a summation in the first and not in the second though?  In the code they are being run the same amount of times  using the same comparison...

Comment: Didn't look at the definitions of your L_i, w_i and didn't look at your context, so I am not sure. But no, the code is fine. You are doing inner loop over j, and 1. you add to dW[: y[i]] for each j not equal to y[i] 2. you add to dW[: **j**] for each j not equal to y[i]. In step 2 you are adding to a different index in the array for each j, so no, there is no summation there.

Comment: Got it, thanks.  If you'd like, you can copy your comments into an answer and I'd be happy to upvote and accept it.

Comment: Hi David, can you explain why `dW[:, y[i]] += -X[i]` and `dW[:, j] += X[i]` do? I still feel confused.

Answer (score 9):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I am answering here. Whenever you compute loss vector for `x[i]`, `i`th training example and get some nonzero loss, that means you should move your weight vector for the incorrect class `(j != y[i])` away by `x[i]`, and at the same time, move the weights or hyperplane for the correct class (`j==y[i]`) near `x[i]`. By parallelogram law, `w + x` lies in between `w` and `x`. So this way `w[y[i]]` tries to come nearer to `x[i]` each time it finds `loss>0`.

Thus, `dW[:,y[i]] += -X[i]` and `dW[:,j] += X[i]` is done in the loop, but while update, we will do in direction of decreasing gradient, so we are essentially adding `X[i]` to correct class weights and going away by `X[i]` from weights that miss classify.